# Default timestamp showing local time in oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have created a table with created_time column which is having default time as systimestamp. 
When I insert  a row to it the time is showing my local time like. 
23-02-18 08:49:05.430419000 AM

But when I query select systimstamp from dual it is showing GMT like 
23-02-18 05:11:04.225141000 AM +00:00

How can I make sure that the default timestamp also consider GMT?

```
CREATE TABLE TS_TEST (
MY_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
created_time TIMESTAMP(6) default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
insert into TS_TEST (MY_NAME) Values ('george');
```

I want the created_time column should be always in GMT

Comment: What tool are you using to query? And please show the table DDL statement so we can datatype and default statement and whether any triggers are involved.

Comment: I am using SQLDeveloper.

Comment: CREATE TABLE TS_TEST ( MY_NAME VARCHAR2(100), created_time TIMESTAMP(6) default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your code, then you should see the problem. You say "**default time as systimestamp**" but your code is `default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

`SYSTIMESTAMP` is different to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

- `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns the current date/time as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in time zone of database server's operating system (not `DBTIMEZONE`!).
- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the current date/time date as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in the current user session time zone (which may change at any time).
- `LOCALTIMESTAMP` returns the current date/time date as `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone information) in the current user session time zone.

I would recommend this one:

```
CREATE TABLE TS_TEST (
   MY_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
   created_time TIMESTAMP(6) default SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)
);
```

or use `created_time TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE default SYSTIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TS_TEST (
MY_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
created_time TIMESTAMP(6) default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
);
```

Comment: Is this intended as an answer to your own question? If so please add a line or two of explanation. But if this is it supposed to be a clarification please **edit your question**.

Comment: default SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) is better than default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'?

Comment: Term `GMT` is a bit old-style. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'` returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` which has to be implicitly converted to `TIMESTAMP`. You solution works but maybe it's not the most "beautiful".