# What is the difference between LOCALTIMESTAMP vs SYSTIMESTAMP in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

As far as I understand SYSTIMESTAMP in oracle returns server's timestamp.But what is the use of LOCALTIMESTAMP in oracle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48941531/1509264

Answer (score 1):

`LOCALTIMESTAMP` returns the time in your current session time zone. This can be different to the database server time zone.

The session time zone in individual for each session and you can change it at any time by yourself.

`SYSTIMESTAMP` returns the time in the database server operating system time zone. Typically as a database user, you cannot change it and it applies for all user.

Comment: Suppose if I am accessing database server from russia then will the session time zone be set to russia's timezone?

Comment: I don't know, it does not matter where your server is located. What matters are the **session** parameters. The default of them could be defined in your client application, your registry (in case of Windows) or your personal environment variables.